# How to create dynamic id to a single button in foreach loop using html & js

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I'v to generate different Id's to a Single button which is under for loop. I'd created table `tbl_tableMaster (id , tblNo )`

I'd created a view which displays the `tblno` on a button by using foreach loop but, what I've to do is:

1. generate different id's to a button
2. `onClick` of any button(btnclick)
   the value should be display on a label(lblTableNo)

---

```html
<?php foreach($tables as $row){ ?>
    <button type = "Submit"
      onclick = "changeLabel()"
      id = "btnclick"
      class = "btn btn-primary mt-1"
      value = "<?php echo $row->table_name;?>" > <?php echo $row->table_name;?> </button>
    <input type = "text"
      name = "txtID"
      id = "txtID<?php echo $row->table_id;?>"
      value = "<?php echo $row->table_id;?>"
      hidden >
<?php } ?>

<div class="card-header ">
  <strong>Table No :</strong> <label id="lblTableNo"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code it works...

```
<?php $no=1;  foreach($tables as $row){ ?>
        <button type = "Submit"
          onclick = "changeLabel(<?php echo $no; ?>)"
          id = "btnclick<?php echo $no; ?>"
          class = "btn btn-primary mt-1"
          value = "<?php echo $row->table_name;?>" > <?php echo $row->table_name;?> </button>
        <input type = "text"
          name = "txtID"
          id = "txtID<?php echo $row->table_id;?>"
          value = "<?php echo $row->table_id;?>"
          hidden >
    <?php $no++; } ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">


        function changeLabel(id) {

         var loanamount = document.getElementById('btnclick' + id).value;

          document.getElementById('lblTableNo').innerHTML = loanamount;

        };
        </script>

    <div class="card-header ">
      <strong>Table No :</strong> <label id="lblTableNo"></label>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could edit the button `onclick` to directly change the label, like this :

```
<?php foreach($tables as $row){ ?>
    <button type = "Submit"
      onclick = "document.getElementById('lblTableNo').innerHTML = this.value;"
      id = "btnclick"
      class = "btn btn-primary mt-1"
      value = "<?php echo $row->table_name;?>" > <?php echo $row->table_name;?> </button>
    <input type = "text"
      name = "txtID"
      id = "txtID<?php echo $row->table_id;?>"
      value = "<?php echo $row->table_id;?>"
      hidden >
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this like `<tr class="tr"><td class="transactionCodeData"><?php echo $transaction['transactionKey']; ?></td>` on one of your table data tag. then on your javascript query

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".approve").click(function(){
                var $row = $(this).closest('tr'); //for the row
                var $transactionCode = $row.find(".transactionCodeData").text();

                //try if the js script works
                alert($transactionCode);

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>controller/method",
                    data: { transactionKey: $transactionCode },
                    success: function(data){
                        location.reload(); 
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: the classes (tr and transactionCodeData) also works on different tags, as long as they are on the same row